# jQuery Selector not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have a jQuery Selector. This one is working.

```
var table_1 = '#table_1 td';

$(table_1).keyup(function(){
   //Some Array Push
});
```

This one is not. Is there any wrong with my syntax?

```
var table_1;

$('#add_button').click(function(){
    table_1 = '#table_1 td';
});

$(table_1).keyup(function(){
   //Some Array Push
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is fine, but the logic is flawed.  In the second example, when the code is run (and the `keyup` function is bound) `table_1` is `undefined`.  Since the jQuery selector isn't selecting any elements, they `keyup` even isn't being bound to anything.  You're not defining `table_1` until the click event is run.

Comment: Assuming that the click event happened, still the selector is not working. But I found an alternative solution to my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is not working because in the second example `keyup` event has been bind with `undefined` as table_1 variable only get the value after click.

There is no need to put table_1 as var and use it. instead of that you can bind and unbind the event if you don't want them to run.

```
$('#add_button').click(function(){
    $('#table_1 td').on('keyup',function(){
   //Some Array Push
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

because you gave the table_1 var a value inside the '#add_button' function.
you need to give it a value before you call for the keyup event listener.